# "Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object" - Angular module import with webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, es6-modules, angular-formly

I'm using webpack and ES6 module in angular 1.x app. In webpack.config I set:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'angular': 'angular/angular',
    'angularFormly': 'angular-formly/dist/formly',
    'apiCheck': 'api-check/dist/api-check',
    'formlyAngularTemplatesBootstrap': 'angular-formly-templates-bootstrap/dist/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap'
  }
}

module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /angular/, loader: 'exports-loader?angular' },
    { test: /apiCheck/, loader: '!imports-loader?angular' },
    { test: /angularFormly/, loader: '!imports-loader?angular,apiCheck' },
    { test: /formlyAngularTemplatesBootstrap/, loader: '!imports-loader?angular,angularFormly' },
  ]
}
```

Now in JS file create module:

```
import 'angularFormly';
import 'formlyAngularTemplatesBootstrap';

export const FormlyUtilityModule = angular
  .module('formly-utility', [
    'formly',
    'formlyBootstrap'
  ])
  .name;
```

Unfortunately I got error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module formly-utility due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module formlyBootstrap due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {"version":{"full":"1.5.8","major":1,"minor":5,"dot":8,"codeName":"arbitrary-fallbacks"},"callbacks":{}} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object
```

Any ideas why 'formlyBootstrap' didn't works ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
import formly from 'angularFormly';
import formlyBootstrap from 'formlyAngularTemplatesBootstrap';

export const FormlyUtilityModule = angular
  .module('formly-utility', [
     formly,
     formlyBootstrap
  ])
  .name;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem still occurs ... Maybe the problem here is webpack / gulp and configuration of loading package

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the second way from angular-formly README?

```
export const FormlyUtilityModule = angular.module('formly-utility', [
  require('angular-formly'),
  require('angular-formly-templates-bootstrap')
]).name;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem still occurs ... Maybe the problem here is webpack / gulp and configuration of loading package